# Qual a quantidade de registros $_POST de um formulario com input dinamico?

Tags: php, sql

Tenho um formulário com campos dinamicos mas percebi que quando envio ele limita a 166 registros.

No meu formulario os campos estão dentro de um WHILE assim:

```
<input name="contagem[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $contagem; ?>" />
<input name="data_pgto[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['data_pgto']; ?>" />
<input name="descricao[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['descricao']; ?>" />
```

Estou capturando o POST assim:

```
  $quant_linhas = count($_POST['contagem']);
     for($i = 0; $i < $quant_linhas; $i++){

         $pgt = $data_pgto[$i];
         $ds = $descricao[$i];
         echo "Data:".$pgt." - Descrição:".$ds."<br>";
     }
```

O formulário é alimentado do SQL e tem 380 registros mas quando envio o POST só vai 166

Comment: No form está imprimindo todos os dados sem problema, mas quando envio não vai todos. Se der um echo na variavel $quant_linhas ele mostra 167

Comment: Está 1000 mesmo, mas em cada linha eu tenho 6 inputs. Matou a charada. Existe alguma forma mais amigável de fazer isso? O problema é que tenho que mostrar os dados para o usuario verificar ou alterar antes de enviar

Answer (score 7):

Verifique a diretiva `max_input_vars`.

Se está realmente certo de que existe mesmo os mais de 300 campos no formulário e sempre chegam como limite de 166, a hipótese mais provável é limitação na diretiva de configuração [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars). O padrão é 1000 mas o seu ambiente pode estar definido com valor de 165/166.

Normalmente quando passa do limite, é retornado o limite + 1 (1001). Se no seu caso mostra 166, provavelmente está como 165. Mas não posso afirmar.

Note que não é permitido modificar em tempo de execução com `ini_set()`.
Mas pode ser modificado se for definido arquivos de configuração customizados com [PHP_INI_PERDIR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php). Ainda assim não poderá mudar em tempo de execução, mas pelo menos não mudará globalmente.

Obviamente, apesar de tudo, certifique-se de que realmente existem os 380 registros. Observe que são 3 de cada (baseado no que postou na pergunta). Portanto estaria com 1140 campos e isso em si já estouraria o limite padrão da instalação.

Dependendo da configuração do ambiente, a requisição é interrompida pelo servidor web. Aqui um exemplo com Apache 2.4.20, Windows 10, Chrome:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um teste ultrapassando o valor de max_input_vars e sequer entra na execução do PHP para poder contar quantos foram recebibos. O chrome retorna essa tela acima. `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`.

O teste foi feito com PHP5.6 e PHP7. Ambos retornam o mesmo resultado.

> Está 1000 mesmo, mas em cada linha eu tenho 6 inputs.

Se possui 380 registros e cada registro gera 6 campos, então o formulário deve possuir 2280 campos. Isso ultrapassa o limite padrão de 1000. Porém, aqui podemos dizer que há uma incoerência. Se estivesse realmente enviando os 2280, o resultado no recebimento seria 1000 ou 1001 ou ainda o erro `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`. Note também que isso pode depender do seu ambiente.

Para sanar a dúvida, certifique-se de que o formulário realmente contém os 2280 campos. Para isso pode usar o JavaScript.

No form defina um id. Exemplo: `<form id="frm" action...`

```
<script>
frm = document.getElementById("frm"); // frm é o id do formulário
console.log(frm.elements.length); // no console log do seu browser exibirá a quantidade de elementos desse formulário.
</script>
```

Particularmente acredito ser algum erro no formulário. Aparentemente não está gerando todos os campos conforme esperado. O motivo é muito óbvio. Se fosse o limite da configuração do PHP, seria cortado em 1000 e não em 166. 
Além do mais num ambiente similar ao de testes que usei, seria exibido o erro do decode.
Há conflitos no que descreveu. Faça o teste com JavaScript.

Comment: Pode ser  o `post_max_size` também.

Comment: O `post_max_size` retorna um warning `Warning: Unknown: POST Content-Length of...` e zera o conteúdo de `$_POST`. Até testei isso para  sanar a dúvida. Não posso afirmar como é o comportamento em outro ambiente como nginx, IIS, Linux, PHP inferior ao 5.6. Acredito que não seja diferente, mas há essa possibilidade.